# Any book for understanding the concept of Random measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Could anyone please give me some references for understanding the concept of random measure? I'm beginner in this field.

Comment: do you mean random variables? or measures?

Comment: Yes, I'm just confused with the term random with measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kallenberg, Olav. Random measures, theory and applications.  Springer International Publishing, 2017.